# !IsPostBack returns always true

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to implement search operation for my gridview.When I load my page first time !IsPostBack works fine but when I click on the search button my page loads again and !IsPostBack returns true value.So, I was not able to perform my search operation
this is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ((Label)Master.FindControl("Label1")).Text = (string)Session["sname"];

        fillData();
    }
}

public void fillData()
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EBR_Supplier where DeleteFlag=" + 0 + " ORDER BY RowId ASC", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adap.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();    
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    fillData();
}

protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = txtid.Text;
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EBR_Supplier where DeleteFlag=" + 0 + " and SupplierId='" + id + "' ORDER BY RowId ASC", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Because the page will send a "post" request when a page is submitted. If you want to implement something when a page is submitted then you can write the code in "Else" part.

Comment: You do know that that including _data_ into in a an sql query like with the `SupplierId='" + id + "'` snippet is **really bad**, right? Have you heard of sql injection?

Comment: @VishalSuthar: It will execute the else block when the if condition  is false my if condition is always returning true value

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn:yes i heard about sql injection. So can you help me how should i improve my query.

Comment: @ChhotumalIngole Can you please Post your '.aspx' page source code ? You may have mixed up something else.

Comment: @VishalSuthar:I am new to posting questions in stack overflow can you  please tell me how to add another code snippet  in this question or should i create another question

Comment: @ChhotumalIngole edit this question and add code in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself I have a form control on my master page.I removed that it helped me.I thank you all for giving time to my question.